# How to Set "Orientation For Preview" to Landscape in Android Studio?

Tags: android-ide

After looking at related questions, they don't answer the my question which relates to the Android Studio IDE.

I'm making an app that should only be used in Landscape Orientation and instead of switching all my *.xml files' previews to Landscape, I'd like to create a new *.xml file and have the preview automatically be in Landscape.

Is this possible? And if so, how do I set the "Orientation for Preview" to default it to Landscape?

The picture below shows the option to change it manually.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to move all of your layouts to `layout-land` folder instead of `layout` folder.